# Unity C#: strange texture/sprite problems

Tags: unity, textures, graphics, sprites

I've been making a gallery style shooting game, like something you'd find at a carnival, with ducks to shoot. I'd made the game and it was all working fine. However opening it today, it doesn't look the same. There are some problems with the GUI graphics. They are drawn like this:

[image: strange texture problems]

The other day when I finished it, it worked completely fine, and unfortunately I don't have an image of what it looked like when working. The code I've used to draw this is as follows:

```
void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, scoreLabel.texture.width, scoreLabel.texture.height), scoreLabel.texture);
    GUI.Label (new Rect (scoreLabel.texture.width - 7, 10, colon.texture.width, colon.texture.height), colon.texture);


    int tempWidth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++) {
        if(i > 0) tempWidth += numbers[int.Parse (charArray[i - 1].ToString ())].texture.width * 2 / 5;
        GUI.Label (new Rect (135 + tempWidth, 13, 40, 30), numbers[int.Parse (charArray[i].ToString ())].texture);
    }
}
```

Previously when it was working, the settings for the sprite/texture wouldn't affect the sprite/texture being drawn. The settings (for the numbers) are as below:

[image: settings]

Can anybody advise me on what to do? I've played with the settings, and restarted unity and my computer and had no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using legacy GUI?

Comment: Nope... I had no idea that it was legacy. I'll look into the new UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to disable 'Generate Mip Maps'. Easy fix for me, just took a bit of messing around to find.

Comment: lol was going to comment the same. But you found out yourself :) This bug was once a nightmare for me hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned legacy UI is not a necessity, you can check the tutorials for new UI.
Some resources: [Unity official tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui)

[3D Buzz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d_l9OmLYTE&list=PLt_Y3Hw1v3QTEbh8fQV1DUOUIh9nF0k6c) youtube tutorial much better

Comment: Is there a way I can fix this problem and keep the legacy UI?

Comment: Never used legacy UI, so don't know. i used either NGUI or Unigty UI